# Django Rest Framework permissions outside Rest Framework view

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

I am using Rest Framework Token authentication. Which means I cannot know if a user is authenticated outside a rest framework view eg:(A regular django view). The Rest Framework token authentication is a custom auth system which can only be used in a rest framework view.

In a normal rest framework view, I can restrict the endpoint for authenticated users by using this:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

But how will I do that for a regular django view. eg:

```
def someDjangoView(request):
    '''
    Note that I cannout use request.user.is_authenticated.
    It will always return false as I am using rest framework token authentication.
    Which means the request parameter should be of rest framework's and not django's built-in.
    '''
    
    content = {"detail": "Only authenticated users should access this"}
    
    return JsonResponse(content)
```

I am stuck in a situation where I have to know if a user is authenticated (custom auth) outside a rest framework view.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`api_view`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator to your function-based view to enable DRF:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes


@api_view(http_method_names=['GET', 'POST'])
@authentication_classes([YourTokenAuthenticationClass])
def someDjangoView(request):
    print(request.user)
    ...
    return JsonResponse(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

DRF builds on top of the builtin Django `contrib.auth` user auth system. So, for regular django views, you can use the [regular methods provided by `contrib.auth`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/).

DRF also supports session-based authentication (usually the default when using `contrib.auth`). This is ideal, for example, when you have some JavaScript code running in the browser with the user's session.

> Note that I cannout use request.user.is_authenticated.
> It will always return false as I am using rest framework token authentication

If you are using rest framework token authentication, then you must use views that are compatible with that. `request.user.is_authenticated` is part of the `contrib.auth` system built into django. However, you must authenticate a user for this to be True. Rest Framework does this for you. If you're not using the rest framework, you must auth the user yourself!

A simple answer may be to decorate your views to make them utilize the rest framework authentication you define:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes(...) # if defaults are not applied
@permission_classes(...) # to apply permissions you need
def view(request):
    return Response({"message": "Hello for today! See you tomorrow!"})
```